# Echo page title from page with custom meta datetime picker

Tags: post-meta

I am using [Custom Metaboxes and Fields for Wordpress](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress)

I am using the `datetime_timestamp` custom meta with a page. I am trying to echo the title of the page I am using the custom meta datetime in. But it is not working. I have the code incorrect. And I may possibly be far off!

I have the code in the header, and I want to display 1 with the closest datetime.

```
global $post;
$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_test_datetime_timestamp', true );
$time = current_time( 'Y-m-d' );
if ($text <= $time)
  echo $post->post_title;
```

It is displaying the title of the most recent title when viewing a page of post. Or if I am viewing a single post page it displays that post title.

I think I might need to make a custom loop possibly. I am a bit lost.

Comment: Do you want to display the title of the **page** with the most recent `_cmb_test_datetime_timestamp`, in the header of whatever page or post you're on, regardless?

Comment: Yes - that is correct. It is intended to be in the header and displayed at all times. The pages are "event" pages and I want them to be able to read that first thing when they read from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should output the title of the page with the most recent timestamp:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'page' ),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // Note was `meta_value` before
    'meta_key' => '_cmb_test_datetime_timestamp',
    'numberposts' => 1,
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
if ( $posts ) echo $posts[0]->post_title;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

To add conditions, use a `meta_query` clause, eg

```
$midnight = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d', time() + DAY_IN_SECONDS ) );
// If setting timezone when saving data, $midnight += get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'page' ),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // Numeric sort.
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_cmb_test_datetime_timestamp',
            'compare' => '<',
            'value' => $midnight,
            'type' => 'UNSIGNED', // Note was missing before.
        ),
    ),
    'numberposts' => 1,
);
```

Comment: Awesome that worked. I know there is always several ways of writing this. I need to be able to link to that page also. With the way its written I dont see how I can wrap the permalink around the title. Any suggestions? I was just reading up on post_type page when this notification came through. I was trying to figure out if I could just use the _cmb custom meta as a "meta_key" value. As you have shown you can.

Comment: how can I change the args to only show one based one based on the meta _cmb_test_datetime_timestamp and the current date? Then it would show the next page with the meta after that date has passed.

Comment: You'd need to add a `meta_query` clause - I'll update the answer with an example...

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't working, I had something very similar to this. I have found tons of examples working with orderby meta_val_num and then the meta_query with the compare and value keys. But let me ask this, would it not work since there is not an actual date field in the database for this meta? Here is a screen shot of this record in the db http://imgur.com/KvKk238

Comment: Ok so it's not a timestamp, it's a date, so you need `meta_value` not `meta_value_num`, and `date()` instead of `time()`, but it's in a poor format to do sorting and comparing on, it should be stored in the DB as YYYY-MM-DD to make things easy, and then formatted for display.

Comment: Ok I see that you're using a [`text_date`](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#text_date) type field, use a [`text_date_timestamp`](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#text_date_timestamp) field instead to store the date as a timestamp, then `meta_value_num` and `time()` and sorting and comparing will work, and you can format for display using eg `date('d-M-Y', $value)`.

Comment: I didnt see you had replied. I will do that and follow up!

Comment: here is my complete code. It still shows events that have a passed date picked for the custom meta for that page. Something is not quite right. `<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => array( 'page' ),
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'time()', // Numeric sort.
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => '_cmb_test_textdate_timestamp',                'compare' => '<=',
'value' => date('D-M-Y', $value), // Current timestamp.
),
),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>`

Comment: I am sorry for butchering up that code

Comment: Just use `'value' => time()` as in the answer example, the `date()` thing was just for when you want to display the date...

Comment: I changed that and it works but still with improper expectations. Once it reaches the date it no longer shows vs showing through the day of the date picked. And once its passed the date it doesnt show the next event date until about 48 hours set passed the current time. So if you had dates set back to back, it would miss the 2nd one. I changed my compare to greater than equal to from the previous setting. I dont know if that really affects this problem though.

Comment: Ok so you want to compare < midnight I think? Eg `$midnight = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d', time() + DAY_IN_SECONDS ) );` (and if using timezone when saving data then also `$midnight += get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS;`)

Comment: Its very weird. That code isn't showing anything. If I change the compare to ">" then it shows an event. But we know thats not correct comparison.

Comment: It might be, it depends on what you want - do you want to show the nearest next event to now? Then using `'compare' => >=` and `'value' => time()`, and sorting `'order' => 'ASC'` instead to get the earliest would do it for you...

Comment: How would I set it to be -6 off UTC so the date/times function correctly with the time set? I have everything working. And created another custom loop using the same meta with different ID. But the time has to be set 6 hours ahead.

Comment: Just `time() + (-6 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS)`, or if you're using the "admin > Settings > General > Timezone" option, then `time() + get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS`.